# Req.params undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So i have this code

```js
router.get('/invite/:invitecode', async(res,req) => {
  return console.log(req.params)
  if(!req.params.invitecode) {
    return res.render('404')
  }
  if(!req.user) {
    res.redirect(`/login?state=invite/${req.params.invitecode}`)
  } else {
    res.render('join')
  }
})
```

And when I go to
http://localhost:3000/invite/fs
It is supposed to return fs as a param, but instead, it console.logs undefined

Why is this happening?

Comment: There's no need for that function to be async. And watch out for `return console.log(req.params)` which will probably prevent any further code from executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are accessing the Response object, you should flip the arguments

from:

```
async(res,req)
```

to

```
async(req,res)
```